# Does casting to a pointer to a template instantiate that template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

`static_cast<the_template<int>*>(0)` - does this instantiate `the_template` with type `int`?

The reason for asking is the following code, which will error at linking time with an undefined reference to `check_error<char>(void*, long)` with Clang and GCC 4.4.5, indicating that it *does not* instantiate the template. MSVC and [GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/mqpSv) however compile and link just fine, leading to the believe that it *does* instantiate the template. However, if you leave out the cast, MSVC and GCC (both 4.4.5 and 4.5.1) will error on `check_error<char>` only (the wanted behaviour), while Clang will error on both calls. Normally I believe Clang when it comes to conforming stuff, but I wonder:

**Which compiler is correct and what does the standard say about it?**

---

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void check_error(void*, long);

template<class T>
struct foo{
  template<class U>
  friend typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T,U>::value
  >::type check_error(foo<T>*, int){}
};

template struct foo<int>;

int main()
{
  check_error<int>(static_cast<foo<int>*>(0), 0);
  check_error<char>(static_cast<foo<char>*>(0), 0);
}
```

Comment: @Matteo: It's not hard to write `enable_if` and `is_same` yourself, which is what I did to test at Comeau, but then I noticed the same as R.Martinho did - Comeau Online does not link. :(

Comment: this looks like ungood design. just Stay Away™ from the dark corners of the language. less problems for you, less problems for others. :-)

Comment: My bet is that a `static_cast` from one pointer to another requires the underlying types to be complete. If the types are not related, the cast must fail, and if they are, then the cast must perform the necessary polymorphic conversions.

Comment: @Alf: But I like compile / linktime errors over runtime errors and this actually makes sense for the application I'm writing (I know, they all say that). :(

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't see that stated explicitly anywhere but I would assume that types must be complete to determine if it should be possible to determine the outcome of the `static_cast`. If that actually has to instantiate the template is unclear to me.

Comment: @pmr: From 14.7: "Implicit instantiation instantiates the declarations, not the definitions." That much will at least be required in order to cast pointers. But the question is more about name lookup that template instantiation, isn't it?

Comment: @Kerrek: Partly, I mainly need to know when the friend function will be introduced into the enclosing scope. And also, if you remove the cast, it works for MSVC and GCC 4.5.1, but not for Clang.

Comment: Have you tried looking at source code differences between gcc 4.5.1 and 4.4.5?

Comment: Is there a reason why you declare `check_error` outside of `foo`? And why do you need the additional parameter? And why is `check_error` a template? Wouldn't the following be simpler (in addition to generating a compile-time error instead of a linker error): `template <typename T> struct foo { friend void check_error(foo<T> *) {} }; template struct foo<int>; int main() { check_error(static_cast<foo<int> *>(0)); //ok check_error(static_cast<foo<char> *>(0)); //!ok` Of course, this code has the same issues as yours (different compilers handle it differently).

Comment: Very interesting question by the way! (As is [your follow-up question about checking the existence of a template instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8393371/20984)).

Comment: @Luc: The reason why different compilers handle it differently is that the technique is flawed and relies on a bug in the implementation. ;) The extra parameters are for choosing the friend function over the free function because a conversion from `int` to `long` would be needed, as such the friend function is a better match.

Comment: @Luc: And the reason I have that free function is that I originally wanted to specialize it instead of overloading it. Sadly, no compiler I tested allowed that, so I settled for overloading. You're right though that I could just remove it theoretically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not the cast that instantiates the class template specialization, but the function call, because the argument triggers ADL . The instantiation is done because the completeness of it may affect the semantics of the program.

That clang does not follow the spec here is known and a PR was sent by me some time ago. See http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9440

Comment: Dang. Any way to achieve what I want here? Compiler/linker error if a certain template has not been instantiated?

Comment: Also, any standard quotes? Or does @Dave already have the correct ones?

Comment: @Xeo the relevant text is what he did *not* put in bold :) It is "or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.". Take note that this is repeated at 14.7.1p5, but there the word *might* is inserted - "might affect the semantics of the program". That was done because prior to instantiation, the compiler cannot know whether or not the semantics could be affected by the instantiation - it only knows after the fact :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I changed the bolded section

Answer (score 8):

n3242 §14.7.1/1

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3),
>   **the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context
>   that requires a completely-defined object type or *when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics
>   of the program.*** The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions,
>   member classes, static data members and member templates; and it causes the implicit instantiation
>   of the definitions of member anonymous unions. Unless a member of a class template or a member template
>   has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated
>   when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in
>   particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless
>   the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

It seems to me that `static_cast` would require the instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions (as you are just dealing with pointers).

n3242 §14.6.5/1

> Friend classes or functions can be declared within a class template. When a template is instantiated, the
>   names of its friends are treated as if the specialization had been explicitly declared at its point of instantiation.

I think that it should link, but maybe someone else can interpret better than I can.