# Undefined class template is not instantiated to check for friend functions

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

The following program compiles (see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3i-p3Z)), but it would not compile if we uncommented the definition of `Buffer`.

```
template <int size>
struct Buffer /*{ char buf[size]; }*/;

template <class T>
struct Wrapper { void operator+() {} };

Wrapper<Buffer<-5>> a;

void f() { +a; }
```

The reason, the uncommented version does not compile: `+a` triggers ADL, and to collect all candidates for `operator+`, all associated classes must be checked for `friend` functions. `Buffer<-5>` is an associated class, so it must be instantiated. Instantiation fails, hence the compilation error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62314317/11279879).

I wonder if `Buffer<-5>` must be instantiated, why don't we have a compilation error, if `Buffer` is not defined?

Comment: That would forbid most incomplete type usages: `Wrapper<Incomplete*>`.

Comment: As incomplete, so no instantiated, its potential `friend` functions cannot participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @Jarod42: So it has to instantiate `Buffer` only if it has a defninition? I see your point: [this works](https://godbolt.org/z/vdqp_U). Compiler does not feel the need to look into class `Incomplete` for `friend` functions.

Comment: `Wrapper<Incomplete*>` and `Wrapper<Incomplete>` are not the same thing.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: In that context, I don't see difference for ADL. (and `Wrapper` doesn't need definition).

Comment: @Jarod42 `Incomplete*` is always complete.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: in both cases, we should instantiate `Incomplete` (if definition is available (name suggest it is not ;) )) to look for `friend` functions.

Comment: @Jarod42 `Incomplete*` has no friend functions. :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: see [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/y5oGpW), we look at `friend` functions of that class.

Comment: @Jarod42 `Incomplete*` is not a class.

Comment: For both `Wrapper<C*>` and `Wrapper<C>`, we look (also) into class `C` for `friend` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** (implicitly) instantiate a class template from only a declaration; you get an incomplete class type, just like from `struct A;` ([[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#2)).  It’s not an error, of course, to do ADL with an incomplete associated class; the class in question is simply not searched for friend declarations.